# TFS Branching Merging structure multiple releases

Tags: version-control, tfs

We are moving from cvs to tfs and basically importing the latest release in tfs and supporting older versions in cvs. I have read through the 75 page TFS Version Control Branching Strategies and it seems would would be using the "Dev and Release isolation" Strategy...but can't seem to picture the directory tree in source control. My boss states we should we should never be developing n MAIN.

I get the MAIN, DEV and REL branches, but our release eng who says this is what the boss asked for started with branches for productX version 10: DEV_V10U01, MAIN and REL_V10U01 for several Products like:

```
CollectionName
    ProjectA
        DEV_V10U01
        DEV_V10U02
        MAIN
        REL_V10U00
        REL_V10U01
        REL_V10U02
    ProjectB
        ...
```

REL_V10U01 has been released to customers, and I guess current development is going on DEV_V10U02, not sure why there is a REL_V10U02 branch since QA has not got a build of U02.

To me this scheme does not seem right. We can have up to 20-30 updates to a release, not only that - when we start next major release - it starts all over so I believe folders should definitely be utilized. Would it make sense to use folders like dev, v10 and rel as in:

```
Collection:
    ProductA
        dev
           v10
              DEV_V10U01
              DEV_V10U02
        MAIN
        rel
           v10
              REL_V10U01
              REL_V10U02
```

Or should it be like:

```
Collection:
    ProductA
        v10
           dev
              DEV_V10U01
              DEV_V10U02
           MAIN
           rel
              REL_V10U01
              REL_V10U02

        v11
           dev
              DEV_V11U01
           MAIN
           rel
              REL_V11U01
```

I'm confused as to why we have a DEV and REL of the same name? To me, I would think we would create the next rel branch, all bug fixes this release would be done on this branch, then merged back to main and from main to dev when that update is released to client.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

For the typical branching patterns, all (most) development should be done in DEV branches.  REL branches are only used to store a snapshot of the code that was released.  You typically shouldn't be doing development in the Release branch.

When you say Updates, I'm going to assume you mean the same thing as features.  So V10 release may have 10 separate features that are part of it.  It sounds like you are trying to do a Branch By Feature model (which results in more merging, but gives more development isolation and release flexibility), if so you would typically have 10 DEV branches (one for each feature/update), they 10 DEV branches get merged into MAIN, then 1 REL branch is created from MAIN that reflects the actual code released.

In short, you should have 1 REL branch for each actual release into production.

Comment: And do not forget to study the Rangers' Guidance https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/. There is a lot of why and when to apply a certain pattern.

Comment: Although many folks disagree with the rangers guidance as overcomplicated and often incorrect. It is a good start but I more often recommend branch by release than main line branching.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, when I say Updates - I mean patches to the main release. We release a major version once a year. A client can and have multiple versions on there system - once they compare results and whatnot they would uninstall previous version.

Comment: couldn't finish my previous comment because it went over 5 minutes, then it wouldn't let me edit it so let me finish:

I mean patches to the main release. We release a major release once a year, and bug fixes(udpates) for however long we support that version (could be 3-4 yrs). A client can have more than one release installed. So the v10 release could 10-20 updates, updates are released every couple months with hotfixes going out asap.